# Ionic Interval does not exist on Observable Geo Position

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

Working on ionic 4 framework, I am trying to set interval on an observable but it's not working, I have tried to include interval in all the ways, still no luck.

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/interval';

  startTracking() {
    this.isTracking = true;
    this.trackedRoute = [];

    this.positionSubscription = this.geolocation.watchPosition()
      .pipe(
        filter((p) => p.coords !== undefined) //Filter Out Errors
      )
      .interval(1000)
      .subscribe(data => { 
          this.trackedRoute.push({ lat: data.coords.latitude, lng: data.coords.longitude });
          this.redrawPath(this.trackedRoute); 
      });

  }
```

Please help me, working on this project from many days, but no solution anywhere.

Comment: What error you are facing ? and why you used setTimeOut() in your code ?

Comment: I am using VS Code editor, it shows red line under interval(1000), it says - property interval does not exist on type 'Observable'<Geoposition>. I want to subscribe to the data every hour or so, testing it with interval of 1000ms . Any help would be appreciable :)

Answer (score 0):

Interval is an observable and not a operator. I don't know what you exactly want to do, but this should work:

```
import { delay } from 'rxjs/operators';

 startTracking() {
    this.isTracking = true;
    this.trackedRoute = [];

    this.positionSubscription = this.geolocation.watchPosition()
      .pipe(
        filter((p) => p.coords !== undefined), //Filter Out Errors
        delay(1000)
      )
      .subscribe(data => { 
          this.trackedRoute.push({ lat: data.coords.latitude, lng: data.coords.longitude });
          this.redrawPath(this.trackedRoute); 
      });

  }
```